# Pseudo-algebraic group

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry, lie-groups

In the book *Introduction à la théorie des groupes classiques* of Mneimné and Testard, they define:

- (Def 3.5.2) A ***pseudo-algebraic group*** as a subgroup of $\operatorname{GL}(n,\mathbb{C})$ defined by polynomial equations with complex coefficients in the $2n^2$ variables $x_{ij}, y_{ij}$ (where $x_{ij} + iy_{ij}$ is the generic coefficient of a matrix)
- (Def 3.7.1) An ***algebraic group*** is a subgroup of $\operatorname{GL}(n,\mathbb{K})$ where $\mathbb{K} = \mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ defined by polynomial equations with coefficients in $\mathbb{K}$ in the $n^2$ variables $x_{ij}, y_{ij}$.

For context: I think their main point for defining this notion of "pseudo-algebraic" is that if $G$ is pseudo-algebraic, then the polar decomposition is stable in $G$ in the sense that if $M = QH \in G$ with $Q$ unitary and $H$ positive definite, then $Q \in G$ and $H \in G$. They apply this to $\operatorname{SO}(p,q)$, $\operatorname{SU}(p,q)$, and $\operatorname{Sp}(n,\mathbb{K})$.

Still, I don't get the idea of this "pseudo-algebraic" definition. This is probably a dumb question, but why not just say a real algebraic subgroup of $\operatorname{GL}(n,\mathbb{C})$ (or $\operatorname{GL}(2n,\mathbb{R})$)? (And isn't it equivalent to say "real coefficients" in the definition?)

Comment: An online search only gives [pseudo-reductive groups](https://books.google.at/books/about/Pseudo_reductive_Groups.html?id=v1utCAAAQBAJ&redir_esc=y). Is the name perhaps differently translated?

Comment: Why is $SO(p,q)$ a "pseudo algebraic group" in your sense? It seems to be a real algebraic group defined as a closed subgroup of $GL(p+q,\mathbb{R})$.